# Call nodeJS to save data in file but get empty content

Tags: node.js, promise

I have `nodeJS` file that does some stuff and saves result in JSON file.

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('promise');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile'); //npm install --save jsonfile

// ...

function writeFile(filename, obj) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        jsonfile.writeFile(filename, obj, {spaces: 5}, function (err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

 writeFile("test.json",{a:"xxxx"}).then(function (results) {

  })
```

But for some reason I get empty file.

However if I use write File Sync:

```
jsonfile.writeFileSync(filename, obj, {spaces: 5});
```

I call node as:

```
$ node Common/BB_validate.js
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you're not using the promise?

Comment: You should catch the error from the promise so it doesn't fail silence.

Comment: @Bergi without Promise - same behavior, empty file.  However `jsonfile.writeFileSync ` works

Comment: @RolandStarke i never enter to `if (err)`

Comment: In that case it sounds like a `jsonfile` bug. Or you're not waiting for the file to get written. Where exactly do you see the empty file?

Comment: @RolandStarke [`jsonfile.writeFile()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile#writefilefilename-obj-options-callback)

Comment: Any chance [this](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile/issues/81) is happening?

Comment: I just tested your code in node. It works just fine. Your working directory is not the same folder as the JS file. Did you check the folder you are executing node from?

Answer (score 3):

Why use jsonfile? I mean, why not use something like the following?

```
var fs = require("fs");
function writeFile(filename, obj) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 5), function (err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

`JSON.stringify` will convert the object to JSON for you (for storage in the file), without the need to import other libraries. When reading the file you can simply call `JSON.parse(readData)` to convert it back to an object.

Comment: Fun fact, if you write to a `.json` file, you can just `require()` it to get the parsed object instead of using `fs.readFile()` and `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good point sir, though if you wanted to read the file asynchronously it might be best to use `fs.readFile()` imo..

Comment: Still empty file. I run `node my script.js` and I never enter to callback of fs.writeFile. Maybe my program finishes before it enters?

Comment: @snaggs it shouldn't, providing it hasn't hung. Are you positive the file path is correct? `console.log(filename)` to make sure it's where you think it is. I also saw that you're importing `Promise` when you shouldn't need to in most cases. What NodeJS version are you using?

Comment: It creates me file but its empty. If ill use `fs.writeFileSync` - works fine

Comment: I found the problem. It was my fault.I had `process.exit(0)` at the end of toor method